# How to call a function when a tab is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

So I am using the tabs widget from jquery ui. I have 3 tabs: Details, Accomodation and Map. When I click on details and accomodation, it displays the text that I wrote in there.

When I click on map the map tab, I want a google map to be displayed. I wrote a function to do that, but it doesn't display when the user clicks on the Map tab.

I have loaded the right gmpas plugins as this code works on my other html page.
This is my google map function:

```
(function googleMaps(){
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
         var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.099332, -110.980656),
                  zoom: 17,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  }
                  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        });
```

here is my tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Description</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accomodation</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">Map</a>

     </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
     <p>some other text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
     <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
        <div id="map">

        </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT = With request I am uploading the script tag as my 3rd tab opens by default which is undesirable:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict();
        $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton;
    }());



        $('a[href="#tabs-3"]').one("click", function () {
  (function googleMaps(){
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.099332, -110.980656),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = map;
    $("#tabs-1").show()
  })();
});


    var slideshow = $(".pgwSlider1").pgwSlideshow({
        transitionEffect: 'fading',
        autoSlide: true
    });
    $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    }); 
    </script>
```

I do have other plugins like pgwSlider. They work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```
$("a[href^='tabs']").one("click", function(){
    initMaps();
});
```

So the solution for you would be on clicking the `Maps` tab, you need to display it, so you can just add an event handler just for that:

```
$('a[href="#tabs-3"]').one("click", function () {
  (function googleMaps(){
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.099332, -110.980656),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  })();
});
```

Comment: When I use your method, it works the first time I press the map tab but then when I go to another tab and then back to the map tab, instead of a map being displayed, it says [object Object]

Comment: @TarikhChouhan Ah, so it has to be once. Updating the answer.

Comment: @TarikhChouhan Check now... `:)`

Comment: yes that works now! thank you very much. One more question, the size of the tab window is too small to see the whole map, It only a couple of pixels in height. Do you know how to increase it? Also, by default, the map tab is open, how can I make the description tab open by default when the page first loads?

Comment: Ah yes, just fixed that issue just before you replied :) And how about the tabs? Do you know how to make the first tab active by default?

Comment: Where did you uploaded?

Comment: @TarikhChouhan Put `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` after `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();`

Comment: you mean put `$("#tabs-1").show();` after `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();`? I did that and the map tab is still open but also the test from tab1 is shown in the map tab until you click on another tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98928/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-tarikh-chouhan).

Comment: Thank you for your help but no need. I found out the problem. I had to initialse which tab should be active: `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    active: 0
   });`

Comment: @TarikhChouhan Awesome. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href^='tabs']").click(function(){

     callAnyFunction();

});
```

This will pick all the `a` with href's starting from `tabs` (that means probably all the tabs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery **[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** function that will trigger one time when the user click on tab that contain map `#tabs-3` since you want to init your map just the first time user clicked :

```
$('#tabs-3').one('click', function()
{
    //init map here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried that method but it doesn't work. nothing gets displayed when I click on the map tab

Comment: Using it this morning in my project and works just fine, check please if your `googleMaps()` function do the expected work.

Comment: it does do the expected work as it works in my other html page just fine. Should I include `document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = map;` at the bottom in my googleMap() function?

Comment: So it should work since the other answer with 3 votes and after the updates is now just like mine with 0 vote :)